# Tkinter get image to follow cursor with prior movements

Tags: python, tkinter

In python, tkinter, I've created a program of a canvas image that I would like to follow the cursor. Here is the code I have used:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

bg = PhotoImage(file="map.png")

mapimg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor='nw')

dragged = False
def drag(event):
    global dragged
    dragged = True

def release(event):
    global dragged
    dragged = False

def moveimg(event):
    global mapimg
    if dragged:
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        canvas.coords(mapimg, x-400, y-300) # - half of canvas size

root.bind("<Button-1>", drag)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
root.bind("<Motion>", moveimg)
```

Here is a gif showing the output of this code:

[image: gif]

As you can see, the image can be dragged, but when clicked again, it resets to its default position at 0, 0. Why does it do this, and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the event is relative to the window, not relative to the displayed image.
If you want to drag the image from where the mouse was last released, then you should store that position in a variable, and translate the image by the stored coordinates. to move the image, you will need to update the stored position with the relative distance between the last event and the current event.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

bg = PhotoImage(file="map.png")

mapimg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor="nw")

gx, gy = 0, 0
old_event = None
dragged = False


def drag(event):
    global dragged, old_event
    old_event = event
    dragged = True


def release(event):
    global dragged
    dragged = False


def moveimg(event):
    global mapimg, gx, gy, old_event
    if dragged:
        gx, gy = gx + (event.x - old_event.x), gy + (event.y - old_event.y)
        old_event = event
        canvas.coords(mapimg, gx, gy)


root.bind("<Button-1>", drag)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
root.bind("<Motion>", moveimg)
root.mainloop()
```